# How I can upload files to Amazon S3 without listing bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to S3 using Angular front-end with S3 Bucket policy as:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1499245520254",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1499245493674",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test-dev/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev"],
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I change the above policy to

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1499245520254",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1499245493674",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test-dev/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev"],
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1499245517941",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where I added:

```
{
      "Sid": "Stmt1499245517944",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev",
      "Principal": "*"
 }
```

adding bucket list deny, the upload fails. Any way how I can upload files without listing bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectACL",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I solved it by just allowing these permissions, apparently bucket list is not needed in this and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `s3:ListBucket` actions covers the [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) and [HEAD Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketHEAD.html) operations. The **HEAD Bucket** operation determines if the bucket exists and you have permission to access it, which seems to be called before any action on objects (such as the `s3:PutObject` action). See [Specifying Permissions in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html).

Comment: So is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @mango: I don't believe so. From my own observation, I have never been able to use `s3:PutObject` without `s3:ListBucket` (although I couldn't find any official AWS docs on why is that).